# How to efficiently draw jagged lines PyOpenGL?

Tags: python, macos, opengl, vbo, pyopengl

So I have some code to draw a series of parallel axes and also plot some data using these axes, the output looks something like this:

[image: Simple Parellel Co-Ordinates Plot]

Now I have implemented this in a number of different ways to try and get the most scalable and efficient method.

All these methods work on drawing one line as a series of segments, where a segment is the line between two axes, because as far as I know OpenGL only allows the drawing of straight lines not 'jagged' ones.

1. By storing the vertices for each line segment in a Python list and using the glDraw command from here specifying 'line' as the primitive.
2. By storing the vertices for each line segment in a VBO such that the data transfer only occurs once to the GPU if I choose to re-draw the scene. Using the glDrawArrays command.
3. By storing a list of the possible axis tick locations (possible vertices for the line
   segments) in a VBO and then specifying an index VBO to define which ticks from the tick
   location VBO a line segment uses. Using the glDrawElements command.

Now the thing is the third method (indexed VBO) will not allow for different colours for different lines as the lines that share a vertex will also share the colour.

I need to establish the best method as I need to actually plot 5,000,000+ lines and my computer hangs when using method 1 or 2 for more than ~10,000 lines.

I can post some code for this if required however I am looking for an explanation as to the best method.

I am using PyOpenGL on Mac OSX 10.9 (Mavericks) and it doesn't support Primitive Restart sadly.

Comment: By jagged lines, are you actually refering to stippled lines i.e. lines made out of small dashes or dots? If so the actual pattern for the line should be done in the fragment-shader.

Comment: If you are tracing a lot ( more than 100000 ) of similar objects, I suggest you look into Instanced Draw ( Chapter 3 OpenGL red book 8th edition ). With the correct implementation, you will benefit of all the cores your graphic card has. I don't know what it can do with lines but for 100000 small icosahedrons, it made the difference between 1 fps and over 100 fps for me.

Comment: @LawrenceKok Sorry I don't mean lines made out of dashed or dots. I basically mean a line between a series of vertices where the line between each two vertices is straight. i.e. From the original picture any single coloured line (there are 3 'jagged' lines in the picture, purple, green and orange)

Comment: @Jean-SimonBrochu Okay thank you, I'll have a look into that, but doesn't that rely upon primitive restarts?